# Openstack: juju-gui col-location with cinder

Tags: juju

I have a trusty / icehouse openstack deployment runnning and need to rehost the juju-gui charm.

Can I safely deploy onto machine0 which currently runs cinder and nova-cloud-controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Main thing to check for is IP port conflicts; if the juju-gui is on 80, and your machine0 has something on port 80, they will conflict. Otherwise, should be no problem, it's common to stick the Juju GUI on a side machine :)

In future we'll serve the Juju GUI straight from the Juju server.

Comment: Deployed on machine0 last night and all seems to be working fine. Thanks